# Problem after importing DXF files from AutoCAD

Tags: import

Here is the Newbie of the blender.
Now, I practice how to import DXF files from AutoCAD LT.
After importing, I found some problems.

[image]

1. Eventhough I imported the 2D drawing, the layers are seperated to another floor. For example, some layers are on the plane where Z=0, but some layers are on the plane where Z=100. I want to place them on the same plane. How can I do that?

※ Original drawing includes more objects. I just left two objects for simplification.

2. In the original DXF file, there are contour lines but they are in the same plane (Since the orignal drawing is 2D). After importing, they make a real 3D contour line. Is this natural or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Hello, I think your original file is in fact in 3D, you just see it from top view Coordinate System. To make everything in a single plane, scale everything along the Z axis by 0

Comment: Oh, your way makes the all objects in the single plane!!!. Thank you. Furthermore, is there anyway that moves all object on the plane Z=0, not scale them? I want to protect the 3D countour line and move object to absolute coordinate where Z=0.

Comment: Set the cursor at origin with SHIFT + C then change the pivot point to cursor by clicking on hte icon left of the magnet icon on the top of the 3D viewport, then type again S, Z, 0 that should scale all objects to 0 relative to origin of the world

Comment: Thanks Gorgious. You are so Gorgeous.